# Dynamics CRM - How to get the second page of a fetchXml query beyond the 5000 elements?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm having a small issue with Dynamics CRM 2016 and fetchXml. In the CRM I have around 35K users. Since it seems Dynamics is limited to retrieve a maximum of 5000 elements per round, I needed to use the pagingCookie feature to retrieve the second page and so on. For example, to retrieve the second page of these records (from user 5001 to 10000) I had to retrieve first the users from 1 to 5000, obtain the paging cookie and relaunch the process with this cookie.

My question is: This requires getting a total of 10000 users while maybe I'm just interested in getting the second page, not the first one. Is there any direct way to get the second page of results without the pagingCookie?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FetchXML next page results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088942/fetchxml-next-page-results)

Answer (score 1):

Hi to get all your result you need to increase the number of page after each call to the crm and add to a list. I don't know what is your language you are programing but I give you a example in .net and I tested and was working. If you need in javascript is the same way.

```
 public IEnumerable<Account> GetAllClients()
        {
            List<Account> listAccounts = new List<Account>();
            int pageIndex = 1;
            int pageSize = 1000;


            while (true)
            {
                // FETCH CLIENTES
                var Fetch = "<fetch version='1.0' page='" + pageIndex + "' count='" + pageSize + "' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>";
                Fetch += "<entity name='account'>";
                //Attributes
                Fetch += "<attribute name='accountid' />";
                Fetch += "<attribute name='name' />";
                Fetch += "<attribute name='accountnumber' />";
                Fetch += "<attribute name='accountid' />";
                Fetch += "<order attribute='name' descending='false' />";
                Fetch += "</entity>";
                Fetch += "</fetch>";

                EntityCollection resultClient = this.crmService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(Fetch));

                foreach (Account c in resultClient.Entities)
                {
                    listAccounts.Add(c);
                }
                if (resultClient.MoreRecords)
                {
                    // Increment the page number to retrieve the next page.
                    pageIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If no more records in the result nodes, exit the loop.
                    break;
                }
            }

            return listAccounts;
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: I think the key point here, is that you don't need to use the paging cookie at all, you can just jump straight to second page by `pageIndex = 2`

Comment: Yes I am sorry I was looking practically for the first part of you post. this track every records, if you want only the second part just put like you tell whit the fix number on the page index.